# Chef cookbook updates content from one commit then reverts back to the previous commit

Tags: git, nginx, chef-infra

I just noticed that one of my cookbooks is having issues.  It seems that the template file I have is being updated to one commit and then being reverted back to a previous commit immediately after.  Here's an example:

`- update content in file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf from 60b9c3 to 6e4e32`

and then after the content is updated correctly:

`update content in file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf from 6e4e32 to 60b9c3`

my cookbook layout is via Berkshelf, i.e. I have a wrapper cookbook for nginx (me_nginx) with the attributes for nginx I need, then a server cookbook which includes the me_nginx cookbook.  There are no attributes being set in the server cookbook and no other cookbooks I could find are using the same nginx cookbook.

I have seen this occasionally but never really taken time to consider why this happens so more than anything I'm curious if it's an issue with my inexperience with Chef or something that is expected behavior.

```
Berksfile
  me-nginx (0.1.24)
    nginx (~> 2.7.6)
  build-essential (2.2.3)
  nginx (2.7.6)
    apt (~> 2.2)
    bluepill (~> 2.3)
    build-essential (~> 2.0)
```

Comment: What command(s) are you running to get the above output?  What does `Berkshelf.lock` look like (perhaps just the bit relevant to `nginx`)?

Comment: Do you have a `template` resource for `/etc/nginx/ngnix.conf` in your wrapper cookbook? The output of `chef-client` should also mention the cookbook and recipe that defines the resources.

Comment: You simply have two template resources with different input values or different .erb source. So each template try to set the file with it's expected content, the last one win but at each run the file is written twice.

Comment: JonoB, added the Berksfile.lock.  @StephenKing, I do override the default template for nginx.conf in my wrapper cookbook using `cookbook 'me-nginx'`  -- I did check chef-client and don't see any valuable input, it just tells me the relative location of the template it's using.  @Tensibai, I don't have another template for this nginx.conf, I'm simply overriding the default one from the community nginx cookbook.

Comment: @MichaelHill `I'm simply overriding the default one` Show your code ! We can't do divination to know is you're doing it right or not.